# Regex for numbers including decimals, seperators, and -+ signs

Tags: regex

Currently, I am trying to write a regex for numbers including decimals, separators, and -+ signs. However, I have run into an issue where numbers starting or ending with **just** separators or numbers with commas are still included when they should not be.

[Link to regex editor with highlighting and visual samples of issue](https://regex101.com/r/n4ZNKU/2)

Current regex:

```
([-+]?[\d]*\_[\d]+)|([-+]?[\d]*\.[\d]+)|([^a-zA-Z\s\_\,][-+]?[0-9]+)
```

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/n4ZNKU/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?!$)[-+]?(\d*|\d+(?:_\d+)*)(?:\.\d+)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/n4ZNKU/3). If you want to allow empty strings, too, remove `(?!$)`.

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `(?!$)` - no end of string allowed at this point
- `[-+]?` - an optional plus or `-`
- `(?:\d*|\d+(?:_\d+)*)` - 0 or more digits or 1+ digits followed with `_` and 1+ digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - an optional sequence of `.` and 1+ digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: My mistake on not including this in the original question, but is there a way to search for strings of characters seperated spaces rather than per string?

Comment: @UnderMyWheel Yes, replace `^` with `(?<!\S)` and `$` with `(?!\S)`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/n4ZNKU/4).